# using multiple form tag and multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working with php, where I face a problem while using multiple form tag and multiple buttons. When I submit "`button1`" it retrieve data from database and show it in `"TextArea1"`. And when I submit `"button2"` it does same in `"TextArea2"`, but when I submit `"button2"` the page is refresh and the value in `"TextArea1"` is clear.

[...here is my code with database](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KwAkB54vAJqZ0sKYjUIFWLMO5S-GK4qk?usp=sharing)

please help me...!
Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Please include the code in your question as a bare minimum improvement.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a  [mcve]._"

Comment: Please include your code in your question then others can see the code and helps you :)

Comment: This is actually a description of well working forms. When you're submitting a form, the server responses with a _new page_, obviously you've to include the data of the first form to the response of the second form too, and vice versa, if the second form was send first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is, store the values in variables and it should work fine.
You can store the values in SESSION.

It should work fine.

One More thing, as Komal said, You Should Use AJAX in order to get results without refreshing page. AJAX works good. I started using with PHP from last 3 days.
It makes UX awesome.

And Divide your PHP codes in multiple files. It makes easier to debug errors.

Google examples and then implement it in your code. It's easy.

See [See AJAX Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you...! SESSION variables really worked.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple forms in page and you do not want to refresh the page, then you should use Ajax to submit the form

Here you can use jQuery library for Ajax to start with. See this link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax.

Also see my article in different ways of using Ajax [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/http-requests-es6-es5-jquery-komal-kedia/).

Answer (score -1):

Keep the data from the textArea1 in a variable `$_Session['textArea1Data']`, then when you fill TextArea2 in the second submit you put the content of `$_Session['textArea1Data']` in its place.
Or 
Retrieve the content of TextArea1 in the second call to the database